# Showing that $k^n$ is an irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$-Module

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

For a field $k$, I want to show that $k^n$ is an irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$-Module, where $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ acts upon $k^n$ by Matrix-Vector-multiplication.

Now, this would be easy to show using the fact that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ is simple as a Lie algebra, but we haven't proven that in this course yet and it seems to me like that should be unnecessary for this exercise.

Showing that the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ on $k^n$ is transitive would clearly also be enough, but again, I am not sure how to do this: Clearly, for any $w, v \in k^n$ there exists some $n \times n$-Matrix $m$ with $mw = v$, however, I do not know how to guarantee that $\operatorname{tr} m = 0$; this seems to be an underdetermined system of linear equations in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*. It suffices to show every nonzero element of the module is a cyclic generator. Indeed, it suffices to show (a) the submodule generated by a particular vector, say the basis element $e_1$, is all of $k^n$ and (b) that particular basis element $e_1$ is in the submodule generated by any other nonzero vector.

If you want more help on (a) or (b), or an explanation why this is a proof, I can elaborate.

Comment: This seems to be essentially the same idea as my third paragraph, right?

Comment: @tolUene Almost but not quite the same. When it comes to constructing elements in the submodule generated by a vector $x$, you're allowed to compose elements of $\mathfrak{sl}_2k$ which means you're effectively allowed to apply matrix elements from outside of $\mathfrak{sl}_2k$. (Indeed, you could show any $sl_n k$-submodule is essentially a $gl_nk$-submodule and vice-versa, because $sl_nk$ has a complementary subalgebra spanned by the identity matrix, and then transitivity is obvious. This has limited generalizability, though.)

Comment: Plus I added the idea of breaking the proof of transitivity into two parts (using $e_1$ as a kind of "middle man"), because I often find that less complex in these kinds of proofs.

Comment: Ah, got it. It's enough to use any nonzero entry of a vector $w$ to give us some standard basis vector, and from there, it's easy enough to construct matrices that give us every other standard basis vector. Thanks!